# For what g, $E(X|g(X)=0$ where $X$ is standard normal?

Tags: expectation

I know if $g(X)=X^2$, the equality holds.  Is there any other $g$?  How can we generalize the case $g(X)=X^2$ (other than $g(X)=X^{2k}$?

Comment: Every even function $g$, to begin with. Or $g=\mathrm 1_B$ where $B$ is such that $E(X;X\in B)=0$. And many more.

Comment: Got it. We just need to partition the domain of $g$ in to segment where $g$ is one to one.

Comment: Hmmm.... There might be cases when this is not even possible.

Comment: Can you give me a little bit more detail to think?  How do you go about proving for the case $g$ is even?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: Yes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y=g(X)$ and let $h$ denote some measurable function such that $E(X\mid Y)=h(Y)$. Assume that $g$ is even. Then $Y=g(-X)$, hence, the distribution of $X$ being symmetric, $(-X,Y)$ and $(X,Y)$ are identically distributed. Conditional expectations only depends on distributions hence $E(-X\mid Y)=h(Y)$, that is, $h(Y)=0$.